# Numerical evaluation of path integrals in quantum mechanics

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Is there material (lecture notes, books, presentations...) on path integrals that emphasizes practical (best: numerical) approximations, without going much into mathematical rigor? Do straightforward approximations exist and work (such as the  Euler method for Ito calculus)? Can you make sense out of formal equations such as 
$$\int D\phi(\cdot)\exp(i\int\phi'(t)^2dt)=\lim_{N\to\infty}C^N\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\exp(i\sum_{n}(\phi_n-\phi_{n-1})^2/N)d\phi_1\dots d\phi_N
$$ 
simply by truncating the domain $\mathbb{R}^N$ suitably (e.g. to $[-N,N]^N$) and  computing the resulting integral with your favorite quadrature rule?